# How to find information on Angular (not Angular 1)

Tags: angular

I've just recently started to learn Angular, and naturally I have a lot of questions.  From what I've read, the first Angular is incompatible with Angular 2 and up, and the latest Angular release is commonly referred to simply as "Angular".

My question is two-fold:

1. When trying to find answers to questions about Angular on stackoverflow and the web in general, what terms can I use so that I only get results that aren't related to the first Angular?
2. Barring a clean/reliable way to do the above, are there any tell-tale signs that I can use to quickly determine if information in a post, git repo, etc is related to Angular's first release?

Especially as a newbie, I don't want to be banging my head against a wall trying to get Angular 1 stuff to work in the current Angular.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append your searches with "angular2" (no space) most people use this in their posts/questions to avoid confusion. Also, the Angular docs are pretty good and have a helpful tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial. Hope that helps

Comment: I have already begun to use "Angular 4" or just "Angular" as a suffix (it's now slowly replacing old Angular 1.x posts), but often use both if I struggle to find results. Also, appending "-angularjs" will tell Google to hide results about AngularJS, which is the v1.x branch, very useful.